# if value exist in dataframe add it to list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames F1 and F2 containing both the column id1.

F1 contains two columns `F1[id1,id2]`.
F2 contains three column [id1,id2,Description]
I wante to test if `F2['id1']`exists in `F1['id1']` OR F2['id2']`exists in` F1['id2'] then i must addd a colmun in F1 with Description of this id1 or id2 in F2` .
The contens of F1 and F2 are [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z35e.png). The Output That im attending on F1 is [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHgt0.png)
I created F1 and F2 like This

```
     F1 = {'id1': ['x22', 'x13','NaN','x421'],'id2':['NaN',223,788,'NaN']}
     F1 = pd.DataFrame(data=F1)
     F2 = {'id1': ['x22', 'NaN','NaN','x413','x421'],'id2':['NaN','223','788','NaN','233'],'Description':['California','LA','NY','Havnover','Munich']}
     F2 = pd.DataFrame(data=F2)
```

## Creation of my list

```
     l1 =[]
     for id1 in F2['id1']:
        i=0
        for id11 in F1['id1']:
           i = i+1
           length = 4 #number of lines of DF1
           #print(id1)
           if (id1 == id11) & (i<=4): 
                 l1.append(F2['Description'])
           else: l1.append('Null')
      print(l1)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a `for` loop; use `merge`:

```
F2.merge(F1, left_on='id1', right_on='id1', how='left')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. but basically i have id1 and id2. I have To do the samething for the two columns.. if F2.id2 exists  in F1.id2 or F2.id1 exists in F1.id1 i return the Description related To this id... thats why i thought To do step by step and work with lists..

Comment: @This In your question you said that F1 has only one column, `'id1'`. Which is it?

Comment: Thank you for your response again .. But  initially F1 contains id1, id2 and 2 contains id1,id2,Description. I have to search F2['id1'] or F1['id2'] in F1['id1'] and F1['id2'] respectivly. I posted for just id1 because i thoght that it is the samething when do it with list. Maybe im wron . Have you any ideas how to do it in the same time fo the two fields(id1,id2) . Thank you AGain

Comment: @This Then, please edit your question to *accurately* state what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *due to changing in question*

I hope I understand your revised question correctly. Anyway, you need to left merge F1 and F2 on id1 with  and continue left merge the result with F2 on id2. After that you `fillna` and drop one of 'Descrition' column.

Assum your F1, and F2 as follows:

```
In [362]: F1
Out[362]:
   id1  id2
0    1    4
1    7    2
2    9    1
3    3    9
4   10    7

In [363]: F2
Out[363]:
  Description  id1  id2
0         One    1    3
1         Two    2    7
2       Three    3    3
```

Merge Left on `id1`

```
In [365]: F1_id1 = F1.merge(F2[['Description', 'id1']], on=['id1'], how='left')
 ...:

In [366]: F1_id1
Out[366]:
   id1  id2 Description
0    1    4         One
1    7    2         NaN
2    9    1         NaN
3    3    9       Three
4   10    7         NaN
```

Continue left `F1_id1` on `id2`

```
In [367]: F1_id2 = F1_id1.merge(F2[['Description', 'id2']], on=['id2'], how='le
 ...: ft')

In [368]: F1_id2
Out[368]:
   id1  id2 Description_x Description_y
0    1    4           One           NaN
1    7    2           NaN           NaN
2    9    1           NaN           NaN
3    3    9         Three           NaN
4   10    7           NaN           Two
```

Finally, `fillna` and drop `Description_y`

```
In [372]: F1_id2['Description_x'] = F1_id2['Description_x'].fillna(F1_id2['Desc
 ...: ription_y'])

In [373]: F1_id2.drop(['Description_y'], 1)
Out[373]:
   id1  id2 Description_x
0    1    4           One
1    7    2           NaN
2    9    1           NaN
3    3    9         Three
4   10    7           Two
```

Comment: Thank you andy.. I have edited my post can you have a look please

Comment: Initially F1 contains id1, id2 and F2 contains id1,id2,Description. I have to search F2['id1'] or F1['id2'] in F1['id1'] and F1['id2'] respectivly. I posted for just id1 because i thought that it is the samething when do it with list. Maybe im wrong . Have you any ideas how to do it in the same time fo the two fields(id1,id2) . Thank you AGain

Comment: I changed the answer base on what I understand your revised question

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried it doesn't give a result that i want to have on my F1. I have edited my post to put pictures of my files . Sorry we have a big jet lag that's why i can't answer on time.

Comment: So, If I understand correctly, 1st picture is your example data and the 2nd picture is the output result you expect/want to see?